# Running Batch File That Execute A GUI Related Task Via WindowService

Tags: c#, session, powershell, batch-file, windows-services

I know that a Windows service cant run a GUI-related task because it doesn't run on the operation system ui sesssion.

I have a batch file that execute a PowerShell script, this script opens the PowerShell console etc..

When i try to run the batch file using a windows service nothing happen. When I try to run this batch using an exe it works. How can I get the service to run such tasks?

Comment: http://andrusdevelopment.blogspot.dk/2008/02/running-powershell-in-c.html here is one who runs the script within the c# code, maybe use can read batchscript file through it

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @Henrik's suggestion, you can execute the commands in the batch file, straight from C# instead, which may work.

```
Process cmd = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.StartInfo = info;
cmd.Start();
using (StreamWriter sw = cmd.StandardInput)
{
    sw.WriteLine("echo command1");
    sw.WriteLine("echo command2");
    sw.WriteLine("echo command3");
}
```